# Return to next line in text using CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-email, line-breaks

I am having a css issue

I have a td, inside it, there is a text, the text as you can see is a code itself, but consider it as text only

my td now is bigger than the expected, because the text inside surpasses the width of the parent, for this I tried this white-space:initial property as you can see, I was expecting the text to never go out from its parent, break to next line inside text ( not words )

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td align="center" style="text-align:center;font-size: 12px;width:130px;white-space:initial;line-height:20px;max-width:130px;" width="130">
       <a class="link-txt" href="%%=RedirectTo(CONCAT(TreatAsContent(@delivery_service_link), '&utm_content=footer&utm_clickposition=delivery_service_copy'))=%%" style="text-decoration:none;color:#2e2e2e;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:20px;white-space:initial; text-align:center;">
                 %%=TreatAsContent(
                @delivery_service_copy )=%%</a>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

end result is bad :

[image]

Expected result :

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated

This is for email development, that's why there is some inline styling

Thanks

Comment: If you want us to help you give us [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) .

Comment: No it's not. To help you, we would need to write the whole table as the issue is unlikely to be in the piece you wrote. That's what "minimal reproducible" means. That's what you provided: https://jsfiddle.net/w6t1d2uv/. How are we supposed to help with that?

Comment: @Will he edited his comment, and all you need to do is think ad a table and tr at the top, so if you have no idea about the solution it is fine, but the code above is enough .. I fixed the issue with adding only one css property to the TD btw .. 
Have a nice day

Comment: Running your code does not really provide any meaningful results, that's not a reproducible code. I can suggest adding `style="width: 100%;"` to the `<table>` tag, but without an actual code it's really just a wild guess. There may be plenty of causes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long text will push layouts out, as you have found.

There is no one bit of code for all email environments, and it's not all CSS (some strip out the CSS or don't support it). Therefore, you'll see `<wbr>` which is an optional break to cover those scenarios.

Here's the snippet:

```
<style type="text/css"> <!-- Put in <head> -->
.wordwrap {
overflow-wrap: break-all; 
word-wrap: break-all; 
word-break: break-all
}
</style>

<p class="wordwrap" style="overflow-wrap: break-all; word-wrap: break-all; word-break: break-all;"><a href="http://www.this.com/is/too/long/for/mobiles">http://<wbr>www.this.com/<wbr>is/too/<wbr>long/for/<wbr>mobiles</a></p>
```

This requires that the information has `<wbr>` inside at the points you want it to attempt a break, so if it's coming dynamically, and you can't edit the dynamic values, it won't work everywhere.